# No acepta asignar el valor de una consulta en una caja de texto

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de asignarle el dato a un "value" en el formulario, pero, por alguna razón me dice lo siguiente (ver imagen). La API funciona, como podrán observar en la misma imagen muestra el arreglo que viene, pero, no sé porque me está diciendo que no reconoce el campo

Código del formulario:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Editarenfermedades = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    var enfermedad;
     
    const[nombre_enf,nombreenfchange]=useState("");
    const[descrip,descripchange]=useState(""); 

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost/API/Catalogos/Enfermedades/SP_ver_EnfermedadesX_ID.php"+"?Id="+ id)
        .then(respuesta=>respuesta.json())
        .then((datosRespuesta)=>{  
                   enfermedad=datosRespuesta[0];
                  //this.setState({datosCargados:true, enfermedad:datosRespuesta[0]});
                  //datosRespuesta[0].Nombre_enf  datosRespuesta[0].Descrip datosRespuesta.Nombre_enf  datosRespuesta.Descrip
                  console.log(enfermedad);  
         }
        )
        .catch(console.log)
    }, []);
     
   
    

    const navigate=useNavigate();

    const handlesubmit=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      const enviarDatos={id,nombre_enf,descrip};
      

     // fetch("http://localhost:8000/employee/"+params.id,{
     //   method:"PUT",
     //   headers:{"content-type":"application/json"},
     //   body:JSON.stringify(empdata)
   //   }).then((res)=>{
   //     alert('Saved successfully.')
    //   navigate('/');
      //}).catch((err)=>{
       // console.log(err.message)
    //  })
    }
    return ( 
        <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">
            Editar Enfermedades
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
            <form   id="webFrmActualizarEnf"  >  
                       <div className="form-group">
                             <label htmlFor="">ID de la enfermedad:</label>
                             <input type="text"   value={id}   name="txtIdenf" id="txtIdenf" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={10}  placeholder="Teclea el ID de la enfermedad" readOnly ></input>                             
                        </div>                    
                        <div className="form-group">
                             <label htmlFor="">Nombre de la enfermedad:</label>
                             <input type="text"  value={enfermedad.Nombre_enf}     onChange={e=>nombreenfchange(e.target.value)}    name="txtnombreenf" id="txtnombreenf" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea el nombre de la enfermedad" required ></input>                             
                        </div>                         
                        <div className="form-group">
                             <label htmlFor="">Descripción de la enfermedad:</label>
                             <input type="text" value={enfermedad.Descrip}   onChange={e=>descripchange(e.target.value)}    name="txtdescripenf" id="txtdescripenf" className="form-control" aria-describedby="helpId" size={50}  placeholder="Teclea Descripción de la enfermedad" ></input>                             
                        </div>                  
                        <div className="input-group">
                             <span className="input-group-btn">                                        
                                <button className="btn btn-success"   type="submit" aria-label="">Guardar</button>
                                &nbsp;
                                <Link to={"/listarenf"} className="btn btn-danger" type="button" aria-label="">Cancelar</Link>
                                &nbsp;
                                <Link to={"/listarenf"} className="btn btn-warning" type="button" aria-label="" id="btnsalir" >Regresar al Listado</Link>
                             </span>                                    
                        </div>                              
            </form>                             
        </div>                
     </div>
     );
}
 
export default Editarenfermedades;
```

Consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bien, puedo pasar los datos por parámetros, pero, considero que tarde o temprano voy a necesitar usar poner los datos de una API (consulta, ya que esto es lo correcto) en los controles de un formulario. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Porqué estas manejando el dato *enfermedad* como una variable y no como un estado?

Comment: Mis disculpas, no entiendo.

Comment: La idea es que si vas a manejar datos que van tomando distintos valores a lo largo del ciclo. O necesitas pasar valores desde un input, lo vayas manejando a través de los states, no de variables - como enfermedad -  tipo JS nativo. Prueba adaptando la variable enfermedad con useState y nos comentas.